# How to set an identity provider "middleware" in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I'm giving NestJS a try and am pretty happy with the results so far. Right now I'm struggling with some concepts that aren't clear enough in my head.

My API has an authorization-token in the format of a cookie (NOT A JWT). When the API receives a request, it has to use said cookie to ask another service (async), which user is sending it and what role he has.

This exchange from cookie to user info should prepend any controller logic and should be applied globally.

I think this can be done via a middleware, an interceptor or a pipe, but which of those is considered the **better** way according to NestJS?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would use a guard for this kind of feature. Check if the cookie exists, if not, there's already a problem, send back a 403 (i.e. `return false`). Otherwise, the rest of the logic can follow and you can attach the information to your `req` object, thereby having it available throughout the rest of the request. As guards are the first of the enhancers to fire, this also ensures that the value is available in interceptors and certain pipes.